# Add to cart not working in Magento 2.2.5 performance testing script "benchmark_2015.jmx" for customer account

Tags: magento2, performance, testing, benchmark, jmeter

In Magento2 - I am using Magento benchmark script **"benchmark_2015.jmx"** for a default Magento(v2.2.5) installation.

In Customer Checkout thread group >> **"Add to cart"** request(http://prntscr.com/mty00o) is failing to add a product in the cart, and redirected to the blank cart page.
Form key extracted in the following request: http://prntscr.com/mty0su

Guest checkout is working fine without any issue.